# D3.js not getting y axis values

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

I took a code for a simple bar chart visualisation from this D3.js [website example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304).

The code takes a tsv file and represents frequency of letters with a bar chart.

In my case i am using a csv file and i am trying to represent population over time.

This is how my csv is formatted:

year     population
2005     273750
2006     273750
2007     273750
2008     274000
2009     274000
2010     274000
2011     274000
2012     274000
2013     275231
2014     274949
2015     276294

This is the code i am currently executing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  d.year = +d.year;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population; })]);

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.population); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.population); });
});

</script>
```

Note: when trying to test if i am getting the correct values:

```
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { console.log(d.year); }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { console.log(d.population); })]);
```

I am only getting returned the the population numbers that are different and not each population number per year (even when each some years have the same value).

As a result i am getting this bar-chart that is not displaying the correct population values [image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is actually displaying the correct population values. 
The values in your data are extremely close in value when the data in scaled from `0`.

If you place a `console.log` statement in your code when the `y` attribute is defined for the rect like so:

```
.attr("y", function(d) { console.log(d.population, y(d.population)); return y(d.population); })
```

You get the following values:

```
273750 4
274000 4
275231 2
274949 2
276294 0
```

The last number shows where the rectangle will stop in terms if pixels and as you can see there is only a four pixel difference between your `min` and `max` population sizes. So there is a difference but it is tiny. To illustrate my point you can add another data point to the csv:

```
2016,100000
```

And I got something like this:
[image]

So you see it is working. Now if you really want to see the difference you need to change the `y.domain` to:

```
  y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {return d.population; }), d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.population; })]);
```

which gives you:
[image]

The difference in the data is more clearly visible. But now you have the issue that the data points which have the lowest population value will have no bar. This can be addressed by determining the lowest value in the data and minus a certain value. This value is then set as the domain minimum or you could hard code a value yourself.

Finally, you probably want to increase the left margin to get the full tick values.

```
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your code.

The problem is that your data minimum value is 273750, and the maximum value is 276294. This is a 1% variation, so in this scale the difference will be unnoticed.

You need to change your scale domain, try something like:

```
y.domain([250000, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.population; })]);
```

This will cause some problems with your y axis, that's why I don't recommend you just to copy and paste the codes, try to go step by step and understand each part of the code.

You can check that your y axis already had a problem. You will need a bigger left margin, try setting to 60: `margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60}`.